# unable to use multiple static paths for frontend and backend in expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express

I am creating a nodejs/backbone application and wish to keep the directories for backend and frontend different. Here is my directory structure:

```
├── backend
│   ├── api
│   ├── file-uploads
│   └── ui
│       ├── assets
│       │   ├── css
│       │   ├── images
│       │   └── js
│       └── index.html
├── frontend
│   ├── assets
│   ├── index.html
│   └── modules
├── index.js
├── npm-debug.log
└── package.json
```

In the index.js file, i have the following code

```
app.use(express.static('/admin',__dirname + '/backend/ui/'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/frontend/'));
```

Now the url / works fine and display the index.html file inside the /frontend directory but the url /admin doesn't work. I am expecting it to display the index.html file inside /backend/ui/ directory. Where I am going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to pass the URL path, `'/admin'`, to [`app.use([path], function)`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use) rather than [`express.static(root, [options])`](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.built-in):

```
app.use('/admin', express.static(__dirname + '/backend/ui/'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/frontend/'));
```

The middleware only expects a single path, so it's currently attempting to serve files from the `/admin` directory on your harddrive.